# Story about first Spacecraft

Tags: story-identification

A couple of years ago I've heard about an interesting (based on the hearing) story.

I didn't know what it is: a small tale or a novel.

The storyline is evolved around a first interstellar Spacecraft and life there - it allows for many peoples to live there. In this story (based on the hearing of mine) the evolution of life of people is described. And the most memorable thing was, in my interpretation:

> Children start to asking, why in the old movies and books the sky often described as blue, red with no stars. But they knew that the sky is **always** black, they knew it by looking out of a porthole.

That's all I remember about the story.

Comment: I've totally read this story, or a similar one - it was a generational space ship, and one of the things it mentioned that stuck with me was that the children believed gravity to be a metaphor, having grown up in zero G.

Comment: In *Orphans*, I think, a priest explains Newton's gravity formula – attractive force is proportional to the product of masses divided by the square of distance – as a metaphor for love; is that what you have in mind, @Tacroy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This wouldn't be, by any chance, [Orphans of the Sky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphans_of_the_Sky), would it?

Comment: That's it. I started to read and recall more details I was told.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to help! :)